# How to get around Chromebook recovery media creation error "download interrupted"

Tags: bootable-media, chromebook

Every time I try to create recovery media, it gets to 93% and then fails with "Download Interrupted"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify you have at least 4GB free:

```
chrome://quota-internals/
```

If you don't, you need to use another Windows, or Mac to do it. Or linux if you follow their linux guide.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to go onto a working computer and create the recovery media there. The steps involve:

1. Opening the chrome browser.
2. Installing the official Chromebook Recovery Utility from the Chrome Web Store.
3. Launching the Chromebook Recovery Utility application and following the instructions there.

[Google Support page reference](https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/1080595?hl=en)